# Converting uWSGI-based Django web app to gunicorn-based one

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, gunicorn

I am trying to run an existing uWSGI-connected Django app (actually a set of apps) under Gunicorn.
uWSGI config is:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python27

home = /var/www/uwsgi/webapp/app/venv
chdir = /var/www/uwsgi/webapp
chdir2 = /var/www/uwsgi/webapp/app
module = uwsgi_app

processes = 150
master = true

socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
socket-timeout = 300

env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
```

And when I try to run `gunicorn` from `/var/www/uwsgi/webapp` using this command line:

```
gunicorn_django --bind 127.0.0.1:9031 --access-logfile /tmp/gunicorn.log --error-logfile /tmp/gunicorn.err --workers=40
```

it starts but I get the following in its error log:

```
2013-09-19 08:17:16 [2981] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 131, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in get_response
    urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 277, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
```

My understanding is that there is no `ROOT_URLCONF` in `settings.py` because middleware should route between several apps with separate urlconfs. But it looks like `gunicorn` is not happy with that. What should I do?

Comment: do you have the request_processing middleware enabled in settings ?

Comment: @karthikr No I do not

Comment: Can you post settings.py? If it's the place where you store your settings

Comment: I guess that is the issue [read point #1 here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it, this app had two different copy of settings, one in `settings.py` (unused) and another one in `./app/settings/*.py` (real). Searching sources for `ROOT_URLCONF` revealed the place where the real settings hid.